# Can not read my glue catalog table from glue notebook with sparkdataframes

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

Hello I have built an apache iceberg database in s3 and added it to glue catalog so that I can query it from athena.

Now I am trying to perform some ETL from glue notebooks but it keeps on returning the following error

> AnalysisExeption: org.apache.hadopp.hive.ql.metada.HiveException: Unable to fetch table my_table. StorageDescriptor#InputFormat cannot be null for table: my_table (Service: null; Status Code: 0; ErrorCode: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null).
> I have tried two way of doing but they both throw the same error
> Scrip1:

```
%connections my-glue-connector
%glue_version 3.0
spark.stop()
sc.stop()

from pyspark.context import SpartContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.sql.catalog.mycatalog','org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog')
conf.set('spark.sql.catalog.mycatalog.warehouse','s3://my_bucket/')
conf.set('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl',org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog') 
conf.set('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl','org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO')
conf.set('spark.sql.extensions','org.apache.iceberg.spark.extension.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions')

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

Script 2

```
%connections my-glue-connector
%glue_version 3.0
spark.stop()
sc.stop()

from pyspark.context import SpartContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

spark = SparkSession.builder\
.config('spark.sql.catalog.mycatalog','org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog')\
.config('spark.sql.catalog.mycatalog.warehouse','s3://my_bucket/')\
.config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl',org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog')\
.config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl','org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO')\ 
.config('spark.sql.extensions','org.apache.iceberg.spark.extension.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions')\
.getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
gc = GlueContext(sc)
```

I can run magic commands to create tables like

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE AwsDataCatalog.mydatabase.mytable\
USING iceberg \
AS SELECT col1, col2(\
VALUES\
(1240,4.3)
)
AS t (col1,col2)
```

But I can not even retrieve that table that I can query in athena so it was indeed created.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

wont work
neither

```
SELECT * FROM my_catalog.mydatabase.mytable
```

I have used this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-the-aws-glue-connector-to-read-and-write-apache-iceberg-tables-with-acid-transactions-and-perform-time-travel/) as a guide.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same error, have you had any luck yet?

Comment: the second script just start working but I had to stop and re-start cause sometime it breaks. It was weird.

Comment: What I picked up is that when you start the notebook, it creates it's own default context and  the SparkConf method is somehow not altering that one.
So it can't find the Iceberg linked catalog rather it's trying to retrieve the Hive metadata store searching for the tables in Catalogue which are not in the Hive Metadata store.